# Preventing pure HTML 5 mobile app from reseting when changing orientation in Android

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

**I am developing a pure HTML 5 mobile app using jquery mobile and very less dependency on Android code apart from loading my main HTML file.**

Following is my MainActivity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    // TO enable JS
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // To enable Localstorage
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html");
    setContentView(webView);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Following is my Mainifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android_playlist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android_playlist.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" 
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

As per the android documentation when the orientation is changed the Android re-loads the activity.
In my case my single activity is a single HTML5 file which contains list of videos. Now when I am testing this on my Android mobile the page reloads itself when I change my orientation.
I would like to avoid this. Can someone please suggest me a way to this.

**Note: in my activity I am just loading this page and rest all code is at client side i.e. using jquery mobile so I am not sure how I will tell my Android to save my HTML5 page state.**

Also, sometimes I noticed that when The app is crashes or if I hit the back button more than once to come out of the **application my localStorage is getting clear.**

I am using following syntax to store any item into localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.getItem()
```

Also I am using following 2 utility functions as I am storing json obj as well into localStorage.

```
Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, obj) {
return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
}
 Storage.prototype.getObj = function(key) {
if (this.getItem(key) != "undefined") {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key));
} else {
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for main activity

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Or you can use

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: I will try this today, in the meantime can you also look at the other issue which I have regarding the localStorage....

Comment: bind local storage with window object window.localStorage.setItem() . are you using phonegap ?

Comment: No, I am not using any phonegap or any other framework

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow your app to be viewed in either orientation, and not have the app restart when the orientation changes, you just need to add screenSize in the activity in your manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android_playlist.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
```